# How to use bitblt in linux?

Tags: winapi, bitblt

Can we use bitblt in linux? I saw a bitblt documentation which states that bitblt was developed to handle graphical operations in windows which confuses me that is it possible to use bitblt in linux.

Comment: Use wine to run Windows application on Linux?

Comment: @linquize Thank You for the reply. But I want to know whether it is supported in linux instead of using some Windows application to run it. Because I have read its documentation and it says that biblt was developed for windows. And can you tell me what is the difference between biblt command and bitblt process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform the same operation on Linux, that BITBLT performs on Windows (which btw, stands for **Bit Boundary Block Transfer**), you can use a the [blit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/blit) function provided by a game programming library called [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/).